# Echo raw query result in php

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I want to print a variable data on UI page.

Below is my raw query :

```
$query = $db->rawQuery("SELECT last_modified,version,last_saved_by from tbl_templates order by id desc limit 5");

    print($query);
```

But it outputs:

```
Array (No data only displaying "Array" as string on the UI page)
```

Comment: `print_r` or `var_dump`

Comment: That's an array. You need to get the value you want out of that array before echoing it out to the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php method print_r();

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>last_modified</td><td>version</td><td>last_saved_by</td></tr>';
foreach ($query as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['last_modified']}</td><td>{$row['version']}</td><td>{$row['last_saved_by']}</td>";
}
echo '</table>';
```